# TypeScript ignoring internal function logic when infering return type?

Tags: typescript

Given the following type definition and function:

```
type SetResponseType = 'returnNumber' | 'returnString';

const argumentTypedFunction = (arg: SetResponseType) => {
    if (arg === 'returnNumber') {
        return 123;
    }

    return 'abc';
}


argumentTypedFunction('returnNumber'); // 123 | 'abc'
```

Why doesn't typescript knows that the return type could only be of type number when 'returnNumber' is used as argument? What do I have to do to make typescript infer the correct type depending on the parameter value?

Comment: Are you expecting Typescript to infer a function type like `<T extends SetResponseType>(arg: T) => T extends 'returnNumber' ? number : string`? Or are you expecting Typescript to look up the definition of `argumentTypedFunction` when it is called, instead of using its return type?

Comment: I expect Typescript to infer a function type like `<T extends SetResponseType>(arg: T) => T extends 'returnNumber' ? number : string`.

Comment: OK. Well, Typescript will never use a generic function signature for an inferred type. You must declare it with an explicit generic signature if you want the function to be generic.

Comment: Could you please give me a short code example of what you mean by an 'explicit generic signature'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your function using a [function overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) and get the inferred return type that you expect. Here's a code sample using the example data you showed in the question:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#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-WbQA-Zst1tttSyAzgAwAN0Y2wMGFs4Bo2B0bEQXHEOgwAPO89ckoA7AA2ACcoRhaiAA)

```ts
/** This signature returns a number when the parameter is "returnNumber" */
function argumentTypedFunction (param: 'returnNumber'): number;
/** This signature returns a string when the parameter is "returnString" */
function argumentTypedFunction (param: 'returnString'): string;
/** This is the implementation signature. It describes a combination of all possibilities */
function argumentTypedFunction (param: 'returnNumber' | 'returnString'): number | string {
  return param === 'returnNumber' ? 123 : 'abc';
}

const num = argumentTypedFunction('returnNumber');
    //^? const num: number

const str = argumentTypedFunction('returnString');
    //^? const str: string

argumentTypedFunction('somethingElse'); /* Expected error 
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
No overload matches this call...(2769) */
```

---

Inference is ok, but being explicit is much better: it defines expectations of the types related to your code very clearly — both for you and consumers of your code — and can help the compiler to better help you in some cases if you accidentally make mistakes in your function implementation.